# InnoDB safe or not safe transaction

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii, migrate

I'm using InnoDB engine to create some tables. I'm doing this with CDbMigration in yii framework.
Here is my similar code:

```
public function up(){


$this->createTable(...);
$this->addForeignKey(..);

}
```

There was an error in adding foreign key and it's clear that migrate up command didn't create foreign keys, But I expected it doesn't create table too(because of InnoDB safe transaction) but it created the table.
Am I in mistake about safe transactions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE` is on the implicit commits list (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html). It, and anything before it, will be commited and won't rollback.